# Hide a column to be sent via mail excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code below which divides every row in a cell based on email address and then sends mail to that email address. However, I am looking to hide the email address when sending the mail (which is column K). I tried to use copyrange function but din't work, can someone help me out with this doubt please?

[image]
Code:

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:K" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 11    'Filter column = K because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add

FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
        FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                               Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

        'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
        If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next

                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail

                .to = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
                .Subject = "Test mail"
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .Display  'Or use Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You wanted to hide the  email address column (K) in the html body while sending email ?

Comment: Yes mate , I want to hide in the HTML Body

Comment: Can you show what your Email is supposed to look like?

Comment: I added the answer. Pls check and let me know

Comment: Hi Pierre, my email column should be hidden in the HTML Body. The problem has been solved now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the code you required. It will copy the range except the last column (email column) and paste into email.

```
With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1)
Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
```

the above code does the trick.below is the full code

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:K" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 11    'Filter column = K because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add

FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
        FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                               Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

        'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
        If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1)
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                End With

                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail

                .to = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
                .Subject = "Test mail"
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .Display  'Or use Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```